# Text-Editing program : muti-search-replace/multi-regex?

Tags: software-rec, search, text-editors, find-and-replace

I have a long and arduous text file, and I need to do lots and lots of the same search-replaces on it inside of selections.

Is there a text editing program where I can do multiple find/replace (or regex) at one time?

That is, I want to : (select text) - (do-find-replace-set-A) - (do other stuff) - (repeat)

Instead of : (select text) - (f&r #1, f&r #2, f&r #3 ... ) - (do other stuff) - (repeat)

I have textpad, but it's macro's won't handle find/replace.

Comment: I see the close for duplicate - can I see the link to duplicate please? That would be very helpful.

Comment: The link someone thinks is a duplicate is this one: http://superuser.com/questions/87544/search-and-replace-tool-that-can-handle-multiple-files-and-subfolders  (note that I did not vote as duplicate, that question asks for any tool, not a text editor specifically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up and started replacing all of the common expressions with a blurb for later with one massive find-replace session as the end for each blurb and it's proper replacement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Emacs, and you wouldn't necessarily even have to learn *much* elisp to do it...

Answer (score 0):

Good old [vim](http://www.vim.org) would be my editor of choice here (or anywhere else).

Answer (score -1):

[Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/uk/site.htm) doesn't support Find/replace in macros, but the TextFX features or one of the plugins might be able to do what you want. If not, you could write your own plugin.

Comment: I could do it all by hand _without_ find&replace faster than I can learn a new language and write a functioning extension.

Comment: Notepad++ does not support "find in selection"

Comment: The plugin list is here: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Plugin_Central

Glancing through the list, it looks like QuickText, RegRexPlace, or one of the scripting plugins might fit your needs.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that "find in selection" was required as well.